# Weird 500 error response from the androidpublisher API, nothing helpful to solve it,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

I'm trying to verify a subscription token.

I'm receiving 500 (null) with no error message from Google AndroidPublisher API. 
My request contains a bearer auth token and a simple GET for the v3 API:

> https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packagename}/purchases/subscriptions/sub1/tokens/{token}

And this is the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": null
    }
}
```

Any idea what a 500 in the internal server could mean, or who I can contact to get this resolved? 
Thanks!